# ANDROID - Crash when I call sendBroadcast to check the network

Tags: android, crash, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a broadcast to check the network, when the network changes state, I notify my activity with onNetworkActivated() or onNetworkInactivated():

```
public class NetworkBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private OnNetworkListener currentActivity = null;

    public NetworkBroadcastReceiver(FragmentActivity activity)
    {
        try
        {
            currentActivity = (OnNetworkListener) activity;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " doit implémenter OnNetworkListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)  
                    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (connectivity == null)
        {
            currentActivity.onNetworkInactivated();
            return;
        }
        else 
        {
            NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null && info.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
            {
                 currentActivity.onNetworkActivated();
                 return;
            }
        }
        currentActivity.onNetworkInactivated();
    }

    public interface OnNetworkListener
    {
        public void onNetworkActivated();
        public void onNetworkInactivated();
    }
}
```

In my Activity, when I I need to call for various reasons sendBroadcast the first time, but Android crash :s

```
public class Earthquake extends FragmentActivity implements OnNetworkListener
{
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private NetworkBroadcastReceiver networkbroadcastreceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        networkbroadcastreceiver = new NetworkBroadcastReceiver(Earthquake.this);
        this.registerReceiver(networkbroadcastreceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
        this.sendBroadcast(new Intent(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        this.unregisterReceiver(networkbroadcastreceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onNetworkActivated()
    {
        Log.e("onNetworkActivated", "onNetworkActivated");
    }

    public void onNetworkInactivated()
    {
        Log.e("onNetworkInactivated", "onNetworkInactivated");
    }
}
```

What is the problem ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you post the error of the crash (check logcat)

Comment: can you send logcat stacktrace

Comment: There is no crash in my Logcat, It's an Android crash

Comment: What is an "Android crash"? If the app crashes, "Unfortunately the app has stopped..", there are LogCat errors and without them it's _very_ difficult to help you.

Comment: Why are you trying to broadcast `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` yourself?

Comment: It's the error :
"L'application SamsungAppsUNA2 (processus com.sec.android.app.samsungapps.una2) a été arrété de manière innatendu. Réessayer."
It's not my application. My application is com.ileotech.earthquake

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: This is the solution:
I register my broadcast and I send with LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Earthquake.this)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17906435/2201919
By @[JoxTraex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529691/joxtraex)

You are not allowed to send this broadcast. If applications could send this broadcast then this could cause problems on the device. This is a protected system broadcast.

Please approach your problem in a different way.

Refer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

Notice how there are only a few methods that use that action. This implies you cannot send this broadcast.