# sendBroadcast ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

Tags: android

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Activity_Index}: 
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast 
android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE from pid=19360, uid=10052
```

Manifest permissions:

```
<!-- Connectivity Manager -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- Connectivity Manager -->


<!-- WIFI -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<!-- WIFI -->
```

Comment: Can you post the code in manifest where you've declared the receiver?

Answer (score 4):

You are **not** allowed to send this broadcast. If applications could send this broadcast then this could cause problems on the device. This is a protected system broadcast.

Please approach your problem in a different way.

Refer:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

Notice how there are only a few methods that use that action. This implies you cannot send this broadcast.

Comment: And how to update the state of the BroadcastReceiver, for example, when the user switched the configuration of the application "Use only WiFi". Or I mast use Update ConnectivityManager??? Thank!